# Translate magento 2 pdf invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, language-package

I installed the MagePlaza language Italian pack on Magento 2.2.3 and it works well, but some voice on the pdf invoice are not translated.

I need to change the **vat** voice to **partita iva**.

I created a **`i18n`** in my theme folder and a **it_IT** csv but it doen't work.

Comment: display Tax or Vat in your pdf file?

Comment: It displays VAT:. I need to change it to : partita iva. There is the same problem in the footer where he displays "order date" instead of "data ordine"

Comment: change "VAT","partita iva" in app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: can you please add "VAT","partita iva" &  "var","partita iva" & "Vat","partita iva" your csv file and check

Comment: i'm doing it. thanks. i must just flush the cache or deploy static content too?

Comment: Yes please flush all caches

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working. it continue to say "VAT:"

Comment: It still appears on admin and on the invoice

Answer (score 0):

Yes @lalit mohan, It is working fine. I have added in Pdf.xml with new field and also added translation file into i18n folder. Thank you